# Database Data transfer from one server to another server in linux

Tags: mysql, cron

Hi this is Ravindra and i have one question that i want to copy table data from one database server to another pc database server periodically after 7 or 10 days automatically in linux through cron job 
Can Any one help me out plz

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to set up [Master Slave Replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) in MySQL. All steps are clearly explained in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) site.

Next, you need to create a shell scripts that contains mysql connection and the commands to start/stop replication.

```
STOP SLAVE;

START SLAVE;
```

Last, you need to set up a cron job to run the shell scripts similar to this.

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month   Month  Day of Week   Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)     (1-12)    (0-6)                
    0       0           *          *        1           sh shell_script.sh
```

Comment: In command section, "sh" in shell_script.sh is necessary?